# Can't CONCAT within query containing GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following query (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
           SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') formatted_calc_dt,
                  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), '')
             FROM calc_calculation_results
         GROUP BY formatted_calc_dt
```

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'my_database_name.calc_calculation_results.calc_dt' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The challenge is:

- I need to concat formatted `calc_dt` with other stuff
- I need to create a view out of this query, so I can't use subqueries

The point of the grouping, if it helps, is to group the dates by hour.

Is there any way I can get what I want?

Comment: It is hard to get a sense of the purpose of the CONCAT with the way the query has been presented (i.e. identical to the formatted_calc_dt).

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense because all the rows gathered by MySQL in a group have the same value for `DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')`. Because this is the expression you group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') formatted_calc_dt,
                  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), '')
             FROM calc_calculation_results
         GROUP BY calc_dt
```

This works since the dates in my database were only stored at the precision level of hours, not minutes or seconds.

I realize this query doesn't make tons of sense as-is. When other columns are involved in makes more sense. Hopefully that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') formatted_calc_dt,
              CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'), '')
    FROM calc_calculation_results
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(calc_dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
```